# JTextArea auto-update and text Limit

Tags: java, swing, text, chat, jtextarea

I'm trying to make a Chatbox using JTextArea.  It will insert a new line of text at 0 to add the text line by line at the top of the TextArea.

I will separate each line with a newline and have word wrap in place, but I'm unable to find a way to limit the number of messages visible at one time.  So if I set a limit of 100, how would I make it so that there cannot be more than 100 messages visible? I want the text to automatically erase the last line and insert the new one.

I know how to do this programmatically, with an ArrayList of Strings that will add a new String with each message, and erase the first index.  But is this efficient? I don't want there to be any noticeable delay while it is looping 100 times and reprinting all the messages with every sent message over 100.

Here is my code at the moment.

```
ArrayList<String> notice = new ArrayList<>();


public void notice(String user, String msg) {
  notice.add(user+": "+msg+"\n");
    if (notice.size() > 100) {
        notice.remove(0);
        getFrame().getGameGUI().getChat(0).setText("");
        for (String s : notice) {
            getFrame().getGameGUI().getChat(0).insert(s,0); //is this ideal with users regularly sending messages?
        }
    } else
        getFrame().getGameGUI().getChat(0).insert(user+": "+msg+"\n",0);
 }
```

FYI, getFrame().getGameGUI().getChat(0) is used to retrieve the JTextArea "noticeChat". I have multiple JTextAreas in a TabbedPane, so I use getChat to retrieve them rather than make a new function for each one.

Sorry if there is any confusion.  My main question is: what is an ideal way to update a finite large JTextArea while users are constantly inserting new lines of text to it?

Comment: You seem to have a number of questions here. Can you (re)state your problem in reply to this so I/we know what it is you want an answer to?

Comment: Write your own document for text area which provides some additional stuff on insertion (deletes the prvious messages for example)

Comment: basically, I'm wondering if my method of updating the JTextArea is efficient.  If not, what is a good way to do what I'm looking for? Again, I am simply trying to make the TextArea remove the bottom message and insert the new one at the top when it reaches its limit (100 for example).  My method is an arraylist that will cycle and insert each string, but at 100 messages being reinserted constantly as users enter messages, I wonder about efficiency.
Sergiy, is my example code not sufficient without creating a new doc?

Comment: Consider using a JList instead of a JTextArea. Then you can simply delete an item in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Limit Lines in Document](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/15/limit-lines-in-document/) for a solution that uses a `DocumentFilter` to remove lines as required.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) like they show in [*Implementing a Document Filter*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter). Using the `FilterBypass`, you can get a reference to the text area's [`PlainDocument`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/PlainDocument.html), and you can check the number of lines returned by the root element. Then you can delete the first line when the line count is over 100.